# python calculator syntax error when everyting is indented correctly

Tags: python, jupyter

```
math = raw_input("Addition + or multiplication *.")

numbers = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to use?")

numbers_list = []

for input in range(numbers):
    new_number = float(raw_input("Enter your numbers.")
    numbers_list.append(new_number)

if math == "+":
    print sum(new_number)

if math == "*":
    import numpy
    product = numpy.product(numbers_list)
    print (product)
```

Comment: Add the 2nd close parenhesy: `... like to use?"))` <-- there

Comment: ^also true for the next `raw_input` call.

Comment: Edit your question and make it code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the brackets that was not closed

And properly indent the code

```
math = raw_input("Addition + or multiplication *.")

numbers = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to use?"))

numbers_list = []

for input in range(numbers):
    new_number = float(raw_input("Enter your numbers."))
    numbers_list.append(new_number)

if math == "+":
    print sum(new_number) # throws error TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable, so it should be
    #print sum(numbers_list)

if math == "*": 
    import numpy 
    product = numpy.product(numbers_list)
    print (product)
```

Comment: And i dont think your logic is right to find the sum and product of numbers